# how to call a PHP function from a form button

Tags: php

I have a form in my `index.html` that looks like this:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="send.php">
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

Inside my `send.php` I have to functions, `function generatekey ()` and `function postData()`, how call I call the `postData()` function from my `action` attribute in my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also make your `action` like this:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="send.php?postData">
```

and in your `send.php` you can do this:

```
if(isset($_GET['postData'])){
   postData();
}
```

Comment: This actually looks better then mine ;)

Comment: @DainisAbols, Thanks. I use this all the time in Ajax calls. I use put all the "ajaxy" stuff in `ajaxCore.php` and send the data with `POST` and the type in the url which will be interpreted by PHP as `GET` (like delete, edit, add..).

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique hidden field in your form like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="postData" />
```

send.php

```
<?php

    function generatekey () {
      // action
    }

    function postData() {
      // action
    }

    if ( $_POST[ 'action' ] == 'postData' ) {
        postData();
    }

?>
```

Or read your submit value, if it's unique.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no "easy" way to do that, you need to write some code in your script that will decide what function to call and when, like:

```
if($_POST['submit'){
   postData();
}
```

Another option is to use one of the many MVC framework out there like [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: This will cause problems, if multiple forms are referring to the same `send.php` file.

Comment: I was just giving an example, on how it would be done in general.