# PHP, AJAX and HTML, function never called

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to call a PHP function from a form button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518422/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-a-form-button)

I've got a button like this:

```
<form method="post" id="submit" action="script/gen.php">
    <input type="button" onClick="getKey()" value="Generate key"/>
```

This calls a javascript in the same file that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getKey() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("innhold").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","script/gen.php?returnKey",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

I know that this javascript is beeing called, by adding an `alert()` several places inside the script. The problem occurs when I try to do an `isset` in my php code:

```
else if(isset($_GET['returnKey'])) {
returnKey();
}
```

This function is never beeing called, even if I add a `echo` before I do the function call `returnKey()`

Can anyone see where the problem is?

**EDIT**

This is what the console has to tell me, from chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/Webpanel/script/gen.php?returnKey. Cross    origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 index.html:37
getKey index.html:3
```

**EDIT 2**

Holy moses, I figured it out. Had to type in localhost/Webpanel in my browser. Its been a long day, so I not quite clear..

Comment: Open this in Chrome, open the console (F12), and check the network panel to see if the request goes through. If it does, it's a problem on the server side. I'm uncertain on whether `$_GET["returnKey"]` would be considered `NULL` or not.

Comment: Add `=` after `'script/gen.php?returnKey'`. and also chech if status is 200 and state 4.

Comment: You could run `echo(json_encode($_GET))` in your PHP to make sure that there is a returnKey property?

Comment: are you running your `index.html` by dragging and dropping it in the the browser's window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved to problem:

I tried to open my `index.html`locally, this is the right way to do it, ofc. Type in `localhost` in the browser. You have to run `WAMP`.